# Registration in django

Tags: django, registration, django-registration

I am looking to add a registration page to my django project. It will need to have perhaps five or six fields. Is django-registration https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/ the best way to go? Or would you recommend something else? Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

django-registration is the first place you should look for signup capabilities in a Django project.

You can use [user profiles](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) to store extra information about users, and you can create your own custom backend for django-registration to provide your own form during the registration process to gather and process this extra information. **Please note** that you **must** use the development version of django-registration (see the [bitbucket page](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/)) to get the easy custom backend stuff right now.

One final caveat - this all assumes you are going to use the Django contrib.auth.User model, which is by far the recommended way to do things (and switched on by default) but some people prefer to roll their own.

Answer (score 2):

The [django-userena](http://django-userena.org/) project seems to be a bit more active, it also comes with ready to use templates. I also use django-registraion a lot and have no problems with it.